# Unable to marshal response: JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Stepfunction which triggers a Lambda. Unfortunately, I can't decode the input correctly:

Input from AWS Stepfunction to Lambda:

```
{
  "MessageNumber": 0,
  "message": {
    "MessageId": "ae5b5d59-6829-4a19-b508-2ba35614e2de",
    "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBJsP+Et+WcgstIR9kkA3sH4UDoxYYcoDT2YYa30K87Rx2wSEFaZNg3CNdsjE18LSDMNXWg7VoV/s/p0bSL0PaUxQ0FV34RAwavG0iGMi",
    "MD5OfBody": "a726ec7fdda41e454850580e1a2cf4b4",
    "Body": "{'stage': 'tst', 'directory': '\\\\\\\\mydomain\\\\data\\\\results', 'variableFilters': ['\\\\filters\\\\x1.txt', '\\\\filters\\\\a1.txt']}",
    "Attributes": {
      "SenderId": "xxx",
      "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "xxx",
      "ApproximateReceiveCount": "2",
      "SentTimestamp": "xxx",
      "SequenceNumber": "xxx",
      "MessageDeduplicationId": "xxx",
      "MessageGroupId": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

The Python code is as follows:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f'Received Event: {event}')
    try:
        body = json.loads(event.get('message').get('Body'))
        stage = body["stage"]
        directory= body["directory"]
    except Exception as e:
        return (e)
```

I get the Error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: JSONDecodeError('Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)') is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}
```

Does anybody has a clue how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, it's all about the "Body" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace simple quotes with double quotes in the `body`.
Because in a valid JSON, strings begins and ends with a `"`

```
body = "{'stage': 'tst', 'directory': '\\\\\\\\mydomain\\\\data\\\\results', 'variableFilters': ['\\\\filters\\\\x1.txt', '\\\\filters\\\\a1.txt']}"
body = json.loads(body.replace('\'', '"'))
```

Comment: Exactly, but how do I get the content of "body" from the given input structure?
Something like `body = json.loads(event.replace('\'', '"'))` isn't possible because the event type dict has no attribute replace.

Comment: `body = json.loads(event.get('message').get('Body').replace('\'', '"'))`